# Handling XML sent in http:

Tags: php, xml

I’m trying to write a PHP page that receives XML from a remote sever (triggered by a third party event such as a message being sent to the server.) Thus, I am not querying a server and processing a response, but rather waiting for a unsolicited (but not unwelcome) call to my page.

If I have the XML in a local file, I can process the XML just fine with:

```
$url = 'xml-file.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

Btw the xml in the file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ALERTSERVICE>
  <PHONENUMBER>1234567890</PHONENUMBER>
  <KEYWORD>Traffic</KEYWORD>
  <CONTENTS>Route 42</CONTENTS>
</ ALERTSERVICE >
```

Can anyone provide with the code substitution for when the same XML is contained in the HTTP, like this:

```
http://www.some_server.com/process_test/process.php?xml=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ALERTSERVICE><PHONENUMBER>1234567890</PHONENUMBER><KEYWORD>traffic</KEYWORD><CONTENTS>Route 42</CONTENTS></ALERTSERVICE>
```

I have the feeling that I’m missing something totally obvious, but have been fruitlessly searching and experimenting, up against a deadline. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you really recieving the XML in a GET variable?

Answer (score 1):

Simple, you can access GET parameter with the `$_GET` superglobal, `$_GET['xml']` in your case:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($_GET['xml']);
```

Passing XML through the URL is not very nice though. Your URL for example is invalid, your server might complain about it:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>400 Bad Request</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Bad Request</H1>
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<P>
The request line contained invalid characters following the protocol string.<P>
<P>
</BODY></HTML>
```

You need to properly `urlencode()` the XML string before using it in a URL, like:

```
http://www.some_server.com/process_test/process.php?xml=%3C%3Fxml+version%3D%221.0%22+encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%3CALERTSERVICE%3E%3CPHONENUMBER%3E1234567890%3C%2FPHONENUMBER%3E%3CKEYWORD%3Etraffic%3C%2FKEYWORD%3E%3CCONTENTS%3ERoute+42%3C%2FCONTENTS%3E%3C%2FALERTSERVICE%3E%27
```

You could make it a `POST` request as well, you can access POST vars with `$_POST` then which works similar to `$_GET`.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably better to POST the XML so you do not have very long URLs (pain for log files) and also have to unescape large GET portions of the URL. Here is the code for POST:

```
$request = new DOMDocument();
$request->loadXML($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
```